# Is there an option to pass the password in the gitpull config of grunt?

Tags: javascript, git, jenkins, gruntjs

I'm trying to run a jenkins build which runs multiple grunt tasks. One of those tasks is to get a pull of the git repository but it requires a git password and I'm not sure if jenkins will prompt me to enter the required password.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    gitpull:{
        set: {
            repos: [
                {
                    path: ['path'],
                    repo: 'https://username@bitbucket.org/abcd/abc.git'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a workaround to enter the password as an option in the config itself?

Comment: If you're really pulling from bitbucket just add public key to your account and use ssh.

Comment: ssh is the best option. dont use password. if you will change it later on it will not work !!!

Comment: Did you happen to try GitHub's version of the URL structure? As in https://username:password@bitbucket.org/abcd/abc.git Not sure it'll work, and, as previously stated, I would not pass it directly in the URL, but you can try it if you like.

Comment: The github structure only works with github repositories in jenkins.